# AS3: simple if condition not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I hav this if condition:-

```
if(leo.blocking == true && leo.leftLimb.hitTestObject(hitList[i])==true){

}
```

its in an enterframe event and leo.blocking is false. but still it is entering the if brackets, ~_~ makes me cry!

Comment: `if(leo.blocking == true && leo.leftLimb.hitTestObject(hitList[i])==true){
  trace(leo.blocking)
}` ... please add this and tell us what is traced.

Comment: ^ thnx dude! it helped.. i was in a wrong impression of trace statements.. turns out i went crazy last night.. xD

Comment: No problem. Remember that Trace statements are an AS3 programmers best friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your conditional is obviously false, but it enters it...

1. Check if your swf is updated(not cached by ide/browser). Add something stupid like `Alert` with message or some color change, or a trace statement if you are debugging.
2. Sometimes watches are displayed incorrectly by ide(but I guess this is not your case, it usually happens for more complicated expressions). In that case you have to add `trace` for your expression to see the real value.

Answer (score 0):

Do u have certain that leo.blocking is true? try to trace leo.blocking.

Doesn't make sense entering on the condition...or maybe leo.blocking changes sometimes.

Do you have more information? It's hard to help like this :)

If you please give me more code to work with I'll be glad to help.

Cheers!